# Empty MSMQ queue

Tags: c#, queue, message-queue, msmq

I'm trying to get messages from a MSMQ queue, my problem occurs when I have messages in my queue and I execute my thread, it was cleaning the queue when this code runs:

```
queue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
```

It means that I'm overriding the queue that had itens, them my question is: how can I get my previously created queue?

**EDIT:**

I'm looking for a method like `GetPrivateQueueByLabel`, but I didn't found!

Comment: If you can, save off the queue (the first time you create it) as a class level variable. Although I'm not sure if `MessageQueue` is thread-safe... so you might have a problem accessing the same queue from multiple threads no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code in place of your code

```
//queue = new MessageQueue();

if(queue.Path==null)
{
     queue.Path = queueName;
}
//now use queue object for further process
```

so that your queue is not replace by previous queue with same name and Microsoft will not allow to create different queue with same name so if queue with same name is already present then it has been used else new queue is create.
Also as per your EDIT your searching for GetPrivateQueueByLabel Method apart from that you can use following code snippet which return array of all private Queue in your Machine (or machine Name which you Provide)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Messaging;

MessageQueue[] privatequeuelist = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(Dns.GetHostName());
```